# Check when an element has been selected/tabbed onto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page where I have a few `div`s with `contenteditable="true"`. I also set the `tabindex` sequentially so when the user hits tab he or she will go through all of the editable `div`s. However, right now I have "Insert notes here" written inside each of the `div`s (see below).

```
<div contenteditable="true" tabindex='1'>Insert notes here<div>
<div contenteditable="true" tabindex='2'>Insert notes here<div>
<div contenteditable="true" tabindex='3'>Insert notes here<div>
```

I'm trying to get rid of the "Insert notes here" text when the user tabs to the `div`. Right now, I'm able to get rid of the text if they click on it with the following jQuery:

```
function selectText(containerid) {
   if(document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML == "Insert notes here") {
      document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = "";
   }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect but also when the user uses tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you are looking for the onfocus event

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

In jquery:

```
$("#fieldId").focus(function() {
    //your code here 
});
```

Comment: Perfect, I completely forgot what that was called haha :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem, please accept as answer as well :) @TimChen

Comment: Yup, definitely! I have to wait a bit more until the site will let me xD

Answer (score 1):

Try this working snippet

```js
$(document).on('keyup, focus', '.editor', function(e) {

  this.innerHTML = "";

  //detect 'tab' key
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    //add tab
    this.innerHTML = "";

    //prevent focusing on next element
    e.preventDefault()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor" tabindex='1'>1
</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor" tabindex='2'>2
</div>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor" tabindex='3'>3
</div>
```